# any viable option for matlab in android?

Tags: android, matlab, opencv, android-ndk, matlab-coder

I am starting a project on android which will need computer vision and image processing techniques. Now i know there are some libraries the popular one being Opencv(which is in C/C++) which would require the NDK.Is there any way the programs can be done in matlab itself and can be converted to java code and then used in the android app.I know that Matlab code can be converted to C/C++ code.However i am not that familiar with incorporating C/C++ code and also i have read that it doesn't support all the features of matlab.
Any good tutorial on using opencv with android will be very helpful.I find matlab to be the best. However I need to keep my options open

Comment: What do you mean? You want to write your app with MATLAB and CONVERT this code to JAVA? REALLY?

Comment: I am considering it.Matlab has lots of inbuilt functions for image processing.Why shouldn't I?

Comment: Octave is possibly an viable alternative (sort of being a Matlab clone) with many functions for computer vision and processing found [here](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/Research/MatlabFns/)

Comment: I think the question is different.Say i have matlab code and i just have to convert it to java on my pc itself and then use it in my android app.why is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to produce a Java component from MATLAB code using the add-on product MATLAB Builder JA. However, this component isn't suitable for running on Android as it depends on the MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR), which has a footprint much too large for a typical Android device.

Typically, if you have MATLAB code that you'd like to incorporate into an Android app you would do one of the following, depending on the purpose and scale of the code you want to include:

1. Deploy your code to a standalone component using either MATLAB Builder JA for Java or MATLAB Builder NE for .NET, put this component on a server and have your Android app call it via a web service, or
2. Use another add-on product MATLAB Coder to automatically convert your MATLAB code to C, which can then be incorporated directly into your Android app.

With route 2, you're correct that MATLAB Coder only supports a subset of the MATLAB language, and you'll need to make sure your algorithm falls within that subset. However, there are only a few major limitations, and so long as you avoid those it's usually not too much trouble. A majority of the algorithms in Image Processing Toolbox and Computer Vision Systems Toolbox are supported.

Comment: However route 2 would need the NDK wouldn't it?
which is something i have not used and i read online that using it is a bit tedious that is why i asked for java.

Comment: That's right. To directly answer what I think is your question: there is no method of converting MATLAB code to Java code automatically; you would need to manually translate it yourself. Although MATLAB Builder JA produces a Java component, it does not do this by producing Java code: instead, it archives and encrypts your MATLAB code, and creates a thin Java wrapper. This wrapper dearchives and decrypts your MATLAB code, and executes it against the MCR rather than MATLAB. The MCR is too large to run on Android.

Comment: I think i understand what you're trying to convey,Thanks for your help